# c++, qt: write a date into a label

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a novice to use c++ and morely qt. I've developed a multi-class software to calculate easter date. Now i'd like to write it to a label on button click, but i get a -i think- segmentation fault. My code is this -just a function, but please, ask if you want to see other parts-:

```cpp
    void MainWindow::on_btn_calcola_clicked()
    {
        Easter *e;
        int anno = ui->text_anno->text().split(" ")[0].toInt();
        int *date = e->dataPasqua(anno);
        int giorno = date[0];
        int mese = date[1];
        QString d = QString::number(giorno);
        QString m = QString::number(mese);
        QString dataCompleta = d+"/"+m;
        ui->lbl_result->setText(dataCompleta);
    }
```

What's wrong? Thankyou so much!

Comment: As the answer points out you did not initialize `e`. Does `e` need to be a pointer? I believe the answer is no. `e` should not be a pointer. You don't want to dynamically allocate memory for `e` and then have to free it in the same function. Does `e` do some internal calculation based on the current date or does it require some other input that you are not giving it? My other advice is to use better naming of your variables. Avoid 1 letter names for variables unless the variable is an index variable (like one you would use for a loop).

Comment: I guess you use a `QLineEdit` for the user input; better use `QDateEdit`. This will also ensure only 'valid' dates are entered.

Answer (score 1):

Variable "e" is declared, but not initialized. 
Possible solution is to use "make_unique" or simple new operator, like:
e = new Easter();

Comment: `Easter e;` might also do the trick; need to replace `e->` with `e.`.

Comment: Probably the only reason you think you need a pointer is because you used `e->` instead of `e.`

Comment: I'm sorry, here you can find the whole project: https://gitlab.com/lucad93/easter.git

Comment: You have a better chance at getting help if you put the required code in the question itself. Remember that the main purpose of a `StackOverflow` question is to help future readers with the same problem.

Comment: `return data;` from `dataPasqua()` is a bug. You can not rerturn a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope. That is Undefined Behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: So, how can i fix it? What can i return?

Comment: You probably should return a `QString` or a `QDate`. But then there is a question why `Easter` is a class at all since it is just a single function with no member variables.

Answer (score 1):

Tried a declaration like below for Easter object.
*(Is better to avoid pointer when is not needed)*

`Easter e = Easter();`

And in a second time, try to return a `QList` instead of a pointer in your function `dataPasqua()`

Is the two potential issues, the rest seems to be ok.